# Which motherboard sizes will fit my case?

Tags: motherboard, upgrade, computer-building

I'm looking to upgrade my PC, it's about 4 years old now and was brought as a custom build from ebay, and came with a gnarly case I'd like to keep. I currently have a [ASUS P5n SLI](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_775/P5NSLI/) with a [NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GT](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/page/geforce_8800.html) for duel outputs, in a [Thermaltake case](http://www.thermaltakeusa.com/Product.aspx?S=1161&ID=1448). I'm looking to upgrade both of these in the near future.

Are their certain types of Motherboard that will fit in my case? If so, how can I tell which type I have?

Comment: Could you tell us the current case?

Comment: @Simon it's linked in the question

Comment: Yep, just realized that thanks to Ignacio's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the case manual:

> Motherboards | Micro ATX (9.6 x 9.6 ), ATX ( 12 x 9.6 )

From this you can see that only a [Micro ATX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroATX) or [ATX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX) motherboard will work with your case. Other types of motherboards, such as an ITX one, will **NOT** be compatible.

Also check out [Darth Android's blog post on choosing hardware](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/20/qotw-how-should-i-choose-hardware/), to make sure you find a proper motherboard and power supply for it.

Comment: .. which means there's a lot of compatible boards out there. You also want to pay attention to your power supply...

Comment: Thats very true, all the top boards right now are ATX and Micro ATX, so finding one would not be an issue.

Comment: Thanks guys, glad to hear it, the power supply is 750W, so should be quite flexible

Comment: Although my edit has yet to be approved, take a look at this @Dunhamzzz http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/20/qotw-how-should-i-choose-hardware/